# How come my two nodes with the same model have different values?

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular-template that looks like this:

```
<div class="radiobutton" ng-repeat="mylabel in field.labels">
    <input
        type="radio" 
        name="{{field['key']}}"
        value="{{mylabel.label}}" 
        id="{{mylabel.name}}"
        ng-model='my_radio_button'
        ng-class='my_radio_button'
    >
    <label for="{{field['key']}}">
        {{mylabel.label}}
    </label>
</div>
```

and a scope that looks like this:

```
{
    key: 'entry.1602323871',
    type: 'radio',
    labels:
    [
        {
            name: 'media',
            label: 'Media'
        },
        {
            name: 'frilans',
            label: 'Frilans'
        }

    ],
}
```

I expect that once I click the first radio-button, both of theese elements should get the class "Media" and once I click the second one, they should both get the class "Frilans", because they share the same model, but when I click the media-element that element get the class Medida, and when I click on frilans that element get's the class frilans, the class isn't removed when I click the other element either. Why?

Answer (score 0):

By using $parent.my_radio_button you access the parent scope rather than the single scope that is created for every single loop.